# Replace a null Array with objects

Tags: java

Code;

```
public Course(Professor professor, String courseName) {
    this.professor = professor;
    this.courseName = courseName;
    this.students = new Student[100];
}
```

By my understanding since the array is initialized its contents are null. I'm trying to write a method called

`public boolean enroll(Student s){...}`

in order to replace the null values with the names of students that are successfully enrolled in the course. Is this possible without the use of lists?

Comment: It would be better to use an `ArrayList` which can grow as needed. To implement it with an array, though, you just need to keep track of `numStudents` so that you know what index to put a new student at.

Comment: The array is not null, but the objects in the array are null. The array is initialized with `new Student[100]`.

Comment: "_since the array is only declared and not initialized_" But it is initialized - the array is not null, the entries are. Yes you can do what you are asking `students[i] = new Student();`

Answer (score 6):

The array is initialized and is not null, however the entries of the array are null. 
It is possible without the use of a list (but it would be simpler).
You need to store additonal information, how many students are enrolled.

```
int numberOfStudents = 0;

public boolean enroll(Student student) 
{
  if(numberOfStudents >= 100) return false;

  students[numberOfStudents] = student;
  numberOfStudents++;
  return true;
}
```

You also need to consider what should happen when there are more than 100 students?

Thats basically what an `ArrayList` does with the advantage that it will automatically grow the array, if there is too much data. If you know in advanced how many entries there will be, you can use `ArrayList(int initialCapacity)` to avoid unneccessary copying:

```
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>(100);

public boolean enroll(Student student) 
{
  return students.add(student);
}
```

Comment: Yeah this was my first method but since the homework is graded via machine, I have to use a standard array for it to count. Thank you for your solution!

Answer (score 5):

The array is actually initialized, to 100 `null` `Student` objects, indexed 0 to 99.

So, assuming that the `enroll()` method is part of the `Course` class, returning `true` whenever it stores a non-`null` `Student` object, it can be implemented as follows:

```
public boolean enroll(Student s) {
  if ((s == null) || (this.counter >= 100)) {
    return false;
  }
  this.students[this.counter] = s;  
  ++this.counter;
  return true;
}
```

where `this.counter` is an integer initialized to `0` in the constructor, after the `students` array is initialized.

A better approach would have been to use an `ArrayList` instead of an array, to avoid having to check the size every time and have no maximum size limitation. In that case, `this.students` would be initialized as

```
List<Student> students;
...
this.students = new ArrayList<Student>();
```

and the implementation of `enroll()` would be simplified to

```
public boolean enroll(Student s) {
  if (s == null) {
    return false;
  }
  this.students.add(s);  
  return true;
}
```

without the need for a counter.

Answer (score 1):

You can enroll a student in two ways:

- Use `ArrayList` instead of array, by this way, you won't need to keep track of last entry or iterate through an array every time `enroll` is called, e.g.:

  `public Course(Professor professor, String courseName) {
      this.professor = professor;
      this.courseName = courseName;
      this.students = new ArrayList<Student>();
  }`

  `public void enroll(Student s){
      this.students.add(s);
  }`
- Use array and iterate through it to find out the last `null` location, e.g.:

  `public void enroll(Student s){
      if(null == s) return;
      for(int i=0 ; i<this.students.length ; i++){
          if(this.students[i] == null){
              this.students[i] = s;
              return;
          }
       }
  }`

In this method, you will also keep track of whether all 100 students have been enrolled already.